# How to extract the YEAR in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+0,0))
```

The output give me the Last Date of the Previous Month of the current date.
How can I extract Year from `DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+0,0))`?

```
Select DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+0,0)))
```

Will the above Select statement extract the Year?

Comment: Is there no equivalent to SELECT YEAR(datefield) in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes, you can use `datepart(yyyy, ....)`.  It turns out that "yyyy" is a synonym for the more commonly used "year" in this context.

However, most people would just use `year(<whatever>)` for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the first case, Does "yyyy" behave as a string? Because, I need to use that Year for numeric calculation?

Comment: The expressions used in `datepart` are language elements in SQL Server.  So, it is not a string; you don't enclose it in single quotes:  `datepart(year, getdate())` or `datepart(yyyy, getdate())`.

Comment: So Can I use that year as an integer?

Comment: @OceanView . . . Yes, the result is an integer.

Comment: Thank you.I have another question. Could you please answer? I wrote a sql query like,

Comment: Thank you.I have another question. Could you please answer? I wrote a sql query for example as, (select f1, f2, f3 from tab1 where...) union all (select f1,f2,f3 from tab1 where....) union all (select f1,f2,f3 from tab1 where...); Here in the output I am getting 3 fields. But, for my fusion chart I need only fields f1 and f2 for x-axis and y-axis. So, can get that result by Select f1, f2 from (select.....union all select ...union all select....)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a function YEAR() so to extract year from `DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+0,0))`
just do `SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+0,0)))`
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/5208

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this case, Does this year behave as a number? Because, I need to use that Year for numeric calculation?